# Similar demonstrative pronouns in several different East Asian language families

Tags: comparative-linguistics

Looking at a list of synonyms in several different East Asian language families, I found that many languages have a similar-sounding word for "this":

- English: This
- Khmer: នេះ (nih)
- Korean: 이 (i)
- Burmese: ဤ (i)
- Indonesian: Ini
- Thai: นี้ (Nī̂)

Is this similarity due to [word-borrowing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Loanword), or does it indicate a possible [genetic relationship](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Genetic_relationship_(linguistics)) between the Austronesian, Austroasiatic, Korean, and Tai-Kadai language families?

Comment: It's ni1 in Cantonese, if you want another data point.

Comment: Of course the null hypothesis is coincidence ;) But there's enough there that it could well be something. I don't know anything about these languages, but I'll be interested to read the answers.

Comment: Persian (Indo-European) īn; Telugu (Dravidian) ī …

Answer (score 1):

The vowel /i/ is  maybe explained by sound symbolism (see also [Bouba-Kiki Effect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bouba/kiki_effect); compare also French *ce ... ci* "this" *ce ... là* "that"), also words for that often come with the vowel /a/ or a variant of it. The common consonant /n/ may indicate some linguistic connection either via inheritance or borrowing.

Comment: Some of these apparent cognates might be explained by the [Austric language hypothesis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Austric_languages), which is still somewhat controversial. The answer depends on whether it is possible to reconstruct the demonstrative pronoun "this" in the proto-languages for each family.